# Invalid record, sequence or computation expression

Tags: f#

I have a function that iterate over a list of a record type:

```
let resAddr (ranges: IpRanges list) =
    ranges
    |> List.iter (fun e ->
                 {
                    let {ipStart=ipStart;ipEnd=ipEnd;subnet=subnet;gateway=gateway} = e
                    printfn "%O" ipStart
                 })
```

The compiler complain with error

```
Invalid record, sequence or computation expression. Sequence expressions should be of the form 'seq { ... }'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't put function body after `fun e ->` in curly braces

Comment: Function body has several lines, how should I then solved the problem?

Comment: Just use several lines as in answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put the function body in braces, F# doesn't use braces for blocks, it uses whitespace. So just make sure to ident your function correctly.

```
let resAddr (ranges: IpRanges list) =
    ranges
    |> List.iter (fun e ->
                      let { ipStart=ipStart; ipEnd=ipEnd; subnet=subnet; gateway=gateway } = e
                      printfn "%O" ipStart
                 )
```

Also, I find that when my functions becomes more than one line I usually prefer to declare them separately like this to help readability

```
let resAddr (ranges: IpRanges list) =
    let internalHandleRange range =
        let { ipStart=ipStart; ipEnd=ipEnd; subnet=subnet; gateway=gateway } = range
        printfn "%O" ipStart
    ranges
    |> List.iter internalHandleRange
```

Comment: From compiler rules, it's not necessary to indent lambdas in the way required for let-bindings. Indentation rules after `fun (...) ->` are special; the lines can be indented much further to the left, even well left of the `fun` keyword. Though the indentation has to be consistent. Personally, I would indent it four spaces with respect to `|>` in this case, with the closing parenthesis on the same level or in the last line, but this is just personal preference. I don't know of any consensus on how to do it.